# Does JBoss Messaging support non-Java clients?

Tags: cross-platform, jms, amqp, stomp, jboss-messaging

For enterprise integration projects, a non-Java access to message brokers like J[JBoss Messaging](http://www.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/) can be very helpful. For the [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org) and the [GlassFish Open Message Queue](https://mq.dev.java.net/) products there are many different client implementations available, using native or standard protocols like [Stomp](http://stomp.codehaus.org).

JBoss Messaging has a task "[Implement STOMP protocol natively](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBMESSAGING-1406)" in the issue tracker. However, this task does not appear in the [JBoss Messaging roadmap](https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBMESSAGING?report=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project:roadmap-panel).

Are there other options to connect to JBoss Messaging with non-Java clients?

Edit: [JBoss Messaging will support AMQP in version 2](http://www.jboss.org/feeds/post/jboss_messaging_to_implement_amqp_and_other_exciting_news)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HornetQ](http://jboss.org/hornetq/) (which will replace JBoss Messaging) will support Stomp clients in version 2.1:

> The HornetQ server will be able to
>   speak the STOMP protocol directly,
>   allowing HornetQ to be used with any
>   STOMP clients which are available in
>   many languages.

http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/Roadmap

It will support AMQP in [version 2.2](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Roadmap):

> Implement the emerging AMQP protocol.
>   We would prefer to implement a
>   simpler, 1.0 version of the protocol
>   that has been agreed upon by all major
>   parties.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss Messaging will support [AMQP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) in version 2, this will allow non-Java clients to access it.